# carousel (slider) got disturbed if I implement the "ng-show" only

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have implemented jquery image slider for my page. it's looking fine by it's width and all. but as soon as I implement 'ng-show' in the body tag for some other requirement, it's getting disturbed by 'width' and the images are being overlapped by some portion to another one.

It's behaving dramatically as when I go for the 'inspect element' for the div consisting this slider. And as soon as I do click only it comes to the correct format itself.

Don't know why it's happening so dramatically.

If I undo (remove "ng-show") it's working fine. But I need to implement ng-show for some other requirement.

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: That class is obviously overriding some of the original CSS. If you post a link or a JSFiddle, we might be help you out a bit more tho...

Comment: I didn't add any css only implemented the "ng-show" in the <body>, that's it. That too the logic of being in correct format is totally surprised if I right-click only and go for the inspect element.

Comment: There has to be something fishy about that class. If it's not CSS (nested, :before and :after elements), it has to be some behavior from JS, which should probably show up in inline CSS tho. I can't really help you without seeing it.

Comment: yeah at runtime it becomes "width: 85px;" while the correct one is "width: 248.75px;" which automatically sets to correct one if i go for the "inspect element" only.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with div's width get smaller or zero. The same issue I got, I solved by runtime given width by calculating total inner image div from a single image div's width.

I ideally take width for calculation when first time load or when the perfect load.

According to the no. of images, width will be increasing of inner div.

**Updated:**
yes, at intial load it is fine, but whenever I upload new image and rebind its width become 0 width. So I give it to runtime accordingly no. of images * single image div width. The reason is, if we given fix width, then right & left arrow will always visible.

So if single inner image div width is 120 & you have 2 image then

carousel's div width = 120 * 2

carousel's div width = 120 * 4 (if 4 image to display)

My sample code which is working now.

```
if (cst_imgcnt)  //this is no of image to display
{
   //set width for each image div width to set 117px
   $('#imageScrollerDIV li', context).each(function () {
          $(this).css({ 'width': '117px', 'margin-right': '2px' });
   });
    //set carousel div width according no. of image with some padding (121 * no. of images )
    var wdh = parseInt(121) * parseInt(cst_imgcnt);
    $('#imageScrollerDIV ul', context).css('width', wdh + "px");
}
```

Comment: At runtime it becomes "width: 85px;" while the correct one is "width: 248.75px;" which automatically sets to correct one if i go for the "inspect element" only.